# LINQ Query - Wrong Count Value

Tags: c#, linq

I am working with some SQL that has been provided and I am running into an issue where the count in the LINQ is different from the count in the SQL and would appreciate some help if possible.

The original SQL that was given is pretty poorly arranged and has a large number of nested queries. This being one of them.  I have broken the query down into its main component and am now stitching it back together with LINQ.

The SQL that I am working with is here :

```
    DECLARE @QSCollectionId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'f52ec043-b360-4266-f95f-08d7c66074pe';

SELECT fieldid
       Count(fieldid) AS fieldcount, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN answer = [value] AND Answer IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END)       AS FieldAnswerMatchCount 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT FCI.fieldid, 
                        answer, 
                        QSA.qsrid, 
                        FAG.fieldid AS dependentfield, 
                        FAG.value 
        FROM   forms.fieldconstraints FCI 
               INNER JOIN forms.sectionfieldmappings SFM 
                       ON FCI.fieldid = SFM.fieldid 
               INNER JOIN forms.qssectionmappings QSSM 
                       ON SFM.sectionid = QSSM.sectionid 
               INNER JOIN sessions.qsr 
                       ON QSSM.qsid = qsr.qsid 
 --AND Qsr.QSCollectionId=@QSCollectionId
               LEFT JOIN forms.answerguides FAG 
                      ON 
               FCI.dependantanswerguideid = FAG.answerguideid 
               LEFT JOIN sessions.qsranswers QSA 
                      ON FAG.fieldid = QSA.fieldid 
                         AND Qsr.QsrId = QSA.qsrid                         
       ) AS 
       FieldConstr 
GROUP  BY fieldid
```

The LINQ

```
var id = Guid.Parse("f52ec043-b360-4266-f95f-08d7c66074be");

var firstResultPartThree = (from fci in FieldConstraints
                            join sfm in SectionFieldMappings on fci.FieldId equals sfm.FieldId
                            join qssm in QSSectionMappings on sfm.SectionId equals qssm.SectionId
                            join qsr in QSRs on new { qssm.QSId } equals new { qsr.QSId }
                            join ag in AnswerGuides on fci.DependantAnswerGuideId  equals ag.AnswerGuideId  into agResult
                            from agJoin in agResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join qsrAnswers in QSRAnswers on new { agJoin.FieldId, qsr.QsrId } equals new {qsrAnswers.FieldId, qsrAnswers.QsrId} into qsrAnswersResult
                            from qsrAnswersJoin in qsrAnswersResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            //where qsr.QSCollectionId == id
                            select new {
                                FieldId = fci.FieldId, 
                                Answer = qsrAnswersJoin.Answer, 
                                QsrId = (Guid?)qsrAnswersJoin.QsrId, 
                                DependentFieldId = agJoin.FieldId, 
                                Value = agJoin.Value
                            }
                            );

    firstResultPartThree.Dump();

var firstResultPartTwo = (from fr in firstResultPartThree
                          where fr.FieldId == Guid.Parse("98CA6B6F-4070-4CEB-E9F1-08D7C66278F9")
                          group fr by fr.FieldId into grp

                          select new {
                                FieldId = grp.Key,
                                Fieldcount = grp.Count(),
                                FieldAnswerMatchCount = grp.Count(x => (Guid?)grp.Key.Value != null)
                          }
                         );
```

The result of the LINQ in the example below gives me

### FieldId                              | fieldcount | FieldAnswerMatchCount

98ca6b6f-4070-4ceb-e9f1-08d7c66278f9 |     4      |    4     |

The result of the sql for the same data is

98ca6b6f-4070-4ceb-e9f1-08d7c66278f9 |     3      |    2     |

The area that I am struggling with is

```
 select new {
                FieldId = grp.Key,
                Fieldcount = grp.Count(),
                FieldAnswerMatchCount = grp.Count(x => (Guid?)grp.Key.Value != null)
```

I understand that the count in the select is wrong, however I do not know how I need to correct it and would be grateful for some help.

Comment: Shouldn't `FieldAnserMatchCount` be something like `grp.Count(x => x.Answer == x.Value && x.Answer != null)`.

Comment: @juharr I love you! that works for the Field Answer Match count, the Field Count is still out though, can you help me on this too please. Also, please put in an answer so I can aware you the points and rep

Comment: I'm not seeing what is causing the other count to be off.  The rest of the Linq seems to match up with the SQL.  I can only suggest trying to return everything from that sub query in the Linq and the SQL for that one fieldId to see what the difference is before it gets grouped.

Comment: @juharr I have just seen I have missed something in the SQL in the question can you take another look please.

Comment: I had some how removed `fieldid` when asking the question

Comment: @juharr I have found the issue, it was that I wasnt calling .distinct() on the end of the part three

Comment: yeah it's easy to miss that since it's at the very beginning in SQL and the very end in Linq